# How to modify code in Python so as to make calculations only on NOT NaN rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have Pandas Data Frame in Python like below:

```
NR
--------
910517196
921122192
NaN
```

And by using below code I try to calculate age based on column NR in above Data Frame (it does not matter how below code works, I know that it is correct - briefly I take 6 first values to calculate age, because for example 910517 is 1991-05-17 :)):

```
df["age"] = (ABT_DATE - pd.to_datetime(df.NR.str[:6], format = '%y%m%d')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

My problem is: I can modify above code to calculate age only using NOT NaN values in column "NR" in Data Frame, nevertheless some values are NaN.

My question is: How can I modify my code so as to take to calculations only these rows from column "NR" where is not NaN ??

As a result I need something like below, so simply I need to temporarily disregard NaN rows and, where there is a NaN in column NR, insert also a NaN in the calculated age column:

```
NR         age
------------------
910517196 | 30
921122192 | 29
NaN       | NaN
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: `df.loc[df['NR'].notna()].xxx`

Comment: When I make it like that: df["age"] = (ABT_DATE - pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['NR'].notna()].str[:6], format = '%y%m%d')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y') I have error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str', could you make another solution ?

Comment: We have to edit this part of line: df.NR.str[:6] so as to take temporarily disregard NaN rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['age']=np.where(df['NR'].notnull(),'your_calculation',np.nan)
```